# Get last Select Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple selects with multiple values (zero,one,two,three,four). If I select `value1`, I check for the last `value1` of all the selects. The actual code does the job.

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw9fW.jpg)

But if I select two `value1` it get the two values

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwKsq.jpg)

What I need is to get only the last select with the `value1`.

```js
$(document).on("change", ".sheet2_etapa", function() {
  var valor_etapa = "";
  $(".sheet2_etapa").each(function() {
    $(this).text();
  });
  var valor_etapa = $(this).val();
  console.log("Valor de la Etapa " + valor_etapa);
  console.log("-------------------------------------");
  if (valor_etapa === "zero") {

  } else if (valor_etapa === "one") {
    $("tbody tr td select [value=one]").filter(":selected").last().css('background', 'red');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="sheet2_etapa">
  <option value="zero">Select</option>
  <option value="one">value1</option>
  <option value="two">value2</option>
  <option value="three">value3</option>
  <option value="four">value4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the last selected option with the value equal to **one** you can write:

```
$('.sheet2_etapa option:selected[value=one]:last')
```

If you need to get the corresponding select tag it's enough to chain:

```
.closest('select.sheet2_etapa')
```

The snippet:

```js
$(document).on("change", ".sheet2_etapa", function () {
    var valor_etapa = $("tbody tr td select [value=one]:selected:last").val();
    if (valor_etapa === "one") {
        $("tbody tr td select [value=one]:selected:last").closest('select').css('background', 'red');
        $("tbody tr td select option:selected").filter('[value=one]:not(:last)').closest('select')
            // deselect
            //.val('zero')
            // reset background
            .css('background', 'inherit');
    }
    $("tbody tr td select option:selected").filter(':not([value=one])').closest('select')
            // reset background
            .css('background', 'inherit');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="sheet2_etapa 1">
                <option value="zero" selected>Select</option>
                <option value="one" >value1</option>
                <option value="two">value2</option>
                <option value="three">value3</option>
                <option value="four">value4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="sheet2_etapa 2">
                <option value="zero">Select</option>
                <option value="one" selected>value1</option>
                <option value="two">value2</option>
                <option value="three">value3</option>
                <option value="four">value4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="sheet2_etapa 3">
                <option value="zero">Select</option>
                <option value="one">value1</option>
                <option value="two">value2</option>
                <option value="three">value3</option>
                <option value="four">value4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello. 1) im using your code and i got the same "error", when i select two options with the same value, both selects get check,remember i need the last select. 2)im using the same class for all selects, thats correct?

Comment: hello, using your snippet and if select value1 in all the selects, in all selects it gets checked, i need only the last

Comment: The purpose of various selects is i can select the same "value1" multiple times in this x selects. BUT the last selected select will do an action.

Comment: @osmelg Snippet updated. Please, can you test and let me know? Thanks

Comment: thats it !. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
this may be useful for you.

```js
$('#sheet2_etapa').on('change',function() {
      var latest_value = $(this).closest('select').find('option')
                          .filter(':selected:last').val();
      console.log( latest_value);
      //alert(latest_value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="sheet2_etapa" class="sheet2_etapa" name="empname" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="zero">Select</option>
      <option value="one">value1</option>
      <option value="two">value2</option>
      <option value="three">value3</option>
      <option value="four">value4</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: hello. this is other good angle, but i need seperated selects